# Fluent nHibernate Many to Many Mapping

Tags: nhibernate, orm, fluent-nhibernate

I have two tables called Users and Roles , and a bridge table to form many to many relation between users and roles. 
My Question is that how can i create mapping for many to many relation in fluent nHibernate.

table User :

  UserID

  UserName

  Password

  FullName

Table Roles:

  RoleID

  RoleName

  Description

Table Bridge:

  UserID

  RoleID

I have mapping tblUser like this

```
class tblUsersMap : ClassMap<tblUsers>
{
    public tblUsersMap()
    {
        Id(user => user.UserID).GeneratedBy.Identity();
        Map(user => user.UserName).Not.Nullable();
        Map(user => user.Password).Not.Nullable();
        Map(user => user.FullName).Not.Nullable();
    }
}
```

and same way for mapping for Role table , but how can i define many to many mapping there?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

see [here](http://wiki.fluentnhibernate.org/Fluent_mapping#HasManyToMany_.2F_many-to-many)

Comment: Yes i already go through this article , n create the mapping as define in the article, but yesterday i go through the Class Mapper tool for Fluent nHibernate, it creates the mapping like HasMany(x => x.tblUserInRoles), actually it create the entity n map classes for bridge table also. is it necessary to create entity n map classes for bridge tables?